# How to get kendoGrid id from DataSource event handler?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid defined inside a razor view `(MVC4)`, and I also have dataSource event handler - onRequestStart like this:

```
function onRequestStart(e){
     var gridId = e.sender...   //the rest of the code
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get `gridId` inside function without passing it as parameter to this function. I also tried:

```
e.sender.element.closest('[data-role="grid"]');
```

and:

```
e.sender.options.table.context.id //('e.sender.options.table' is null)
```

but it doesn't work! `Kendo` version `2016.1.226`

Comment: A data source can be connected to more than one grid.  If you need a specific grid, use the name specified in the razor code that declares the grid. So for `Html.kendo().Grid<modelClass>().Name("myGrid")...` the onRequestStart would have `grid_component = $("#myGrid").data('kendoGrid');`

Comment: Yes, but I am developing a dynamic method for each grid in application. That is the reason I need to catch gridId information from dataSource.

Comment: I think the 'listening/handling' concept in kendo widgets is done by having them bind the change event of the associated data source to an anonymous function that references the widget.  That anonymity makes 'getting a list of listeners' a trickier process than it sounds.  If you examine the data source's `._events` property it will be an array of things bound to it.  What is the nature of the dynamism such that you need to know the grid(s) using the data source at request start time ?

Comment: I want to show custom data loader on all "read" request starts, and hide it after the dataBound is over. This should generally be done globaly in one function for every grid.

Comment: @DzananBegovic Could you please take the time to review the answer and see if it would solve your issue?

Comment: @DavidLebee Yes, this actualy works. Thank you very much. Still there is only one small problem with this approach. Every e.sender sender object will have attachedObject, every attachedObject will have nested dataSource, every dataSource will have attached grid and so on... We are basically getting something like "infinite nested" object.

Comment: How are you getting a infinite nested object are you trying to loop through them?

because technically my example shows how to set a single property during the creation of the data source.
and yes only data source attached to a grid will have the property attachedGrid.

Comment: No I'm no trying to loop trough item, I'm just saying that your method generates additional field that has infinite nested property.Check this image: [link](http://prntscr.com/iqxx7b)

Comment: Actually, I can extend dataSource object only with gridId field. Thank you very much for your help. Regards

Comment: I saw your link shouldn't cause any issues its not a copy its a reference, but you can assign just the grid id as well its fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom grid widget like so and add the attached grid if you don't ever use it for more than one grid at a time.

here is the dojo for it.
https://dojo.telerik.com/OSovidOy

```
<div id="my-grid"></div>
  <script>

    var CustomGrid = kendo.ui.Grid.extend({
        options: {
            name: 'CustomGrid'
        },
        _dataSource: function() {
          kendo.ui.Grid.fn._dataSource.call(this);
          this.dataSource.attachedGrid = this;
        }
    });

    kendo.ui.plugin(CustomGrid);

    $('#my-grid').kendoCustomGrid({
        dataSource: {
          requestStart: function(e) {
                console.log(e.sender.attachedGrid);
                var gridId = e.sender.attachedGrid.element.attr('id');
          },
          data: [
            { id: 1, fullname: 'David Lebee' }, 
            { id: 2, fullname: 'Chuck Norris' } 
          ]
        }
    });
  </script>
```

More hackish less clean if you ask me, but since you are using CSharp builders I doubt you want to inherit their fluent builder (having to go through this trouble once).

You can override the grid by your own widget class like so.

here is the dojo again:

https://dojo.telerik.com/ISUxAWoj

```
<div id="my-grid"></div>
  <script>

    var originalDataSourceMethod = kendo.ui.Grid.fn._dataSource;

    var overrideGrid = kendo.ui.Grid.extend({
        _dataSource: function() {
          originalDataSourceMethod.call(this);
          this.dataSource.attachedGrid = this;
        }
    });

    kendo.ui.plugin(overrideGrid);

    $('#my-grid').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
          requestStart: function(e) {
                console.log(e.sender.attachedGrid);
                var gridId = e.sender.attachedGrid.element.attr('id');
          },
          data: [
            { id: 1, fullname: 'David Lebee' }, 
            { id: 2, fullname: 'Chuck Norris' } 
          ]
        }
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it is probably simplest to configure the grid databinding and dataBound events of each grid you want to show something for.

So, in the .cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<grid-1-model-class>()
  .Name("grid1")
  .Events(events => {
     events.DataBinding("commonDataBinding");
     events.DataBound("commonDataBound");
  })
  .DataSource (...)
  .Columns(...)
  ...
)

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<grid-2-model-class>()
  .Name("grid2")
  .Events(events => {
     events.DataBinding("commonDataBinding");
     events.DataBound("commonDataBound");
  })
  .DataSource (...)
  .Columns(...)
  ...
)

<script>
function commonDataBinding(e) {
  // going for data
}
function commonDataBound(e) {
  // data is gotten
}
</script>
```

`e.sender` will be the kendo grid component.

Comment: Yes, your solution seems fine. I already tried this approach, but I'm currently working on solution that already has implemented this two methods, so my code inside this methods doesn't have behaviour as I expected. Anyway, thanks for help, it seems that I need to find another solution for this problem.

Comment: What about event on datasource? it will give reference of datasource.